# dplyr package and select command conflict

Tags: dplyr

I have a problem with the command select from the package dplyr. I am new on R and I spent an hour with the issue without figuring out what's wrong.

When I do:

```
select(data, ident)
```

R says "Error in select(lecture, ident) : unused argument (ident)"

while when I do

```
dplyr::  select(data, ident)
```

It works well. I assumed that there must be a conflict betwen dplyr and another package. So I remove all packages from my library but I am still getting the error.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you post an example of your `sessionInfo()` output from the console here? Alternatively what happens in the help window when you try `?select`, I am imagining you have dplyr loading a package early in your load order. Below is code I use for loading packages for a project I am working on where I need a number of packages which loads them from the bottom of this list to the top in order to have dplyr's functions not be masked by another package.

```
# Packages Enablement -----------------------------------------------------
require(checkpoint)
setSnapshot("2019-11-04") ##NOTE: must be YYYY-MM-DD

pkgs<-rev(c("dplyr", "stringr", "tidyr", "data.table",
            "readtext",  #better than pdftools
            "lubridate", #For dates
            "readxl",    #For reading excel files
            "openxlsx",  #For exporting to excel
            "skimr",     #gives good glance at data patterns
            "gdata",     #has some very useful 
            "qdapRegex", #contained 'canned' regex expressions for common things
            "tictoc",    #code runtime timer tic() until toc()
            "beepr",     #Makes sounds to signal finished chunks
            "svDialogs", #used to request user for input if critical variables are missing.
            "ggplot2",   #For use in quick plotting prior to tableau
            "parallel"   #for multicore capable functions
            )) #Reversed for 1st package priority

#as.data.frame(lapply(pkgs, install.packages))
as.data.frame(lapply(pkgs, require, character.only=TRUE))
sessionInfo()
```